# Is there any way to determine if a package has state in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, package, state

Is there any way in Oracle to determine whether a package has state or is stateless? I'm not aware of any view in the data dictionary that contains that information.

The "ORA-04068: existing state of packages string has been discarded" error is rather annoying. It can be eliminated by removing package variables from the package. 11g introduced the feature that a package with variables that are all compile-time constants will be treated as stateless.

I could have two sessions and compile the package in one and call it in the other and see if it throws an exception, but that requires calling a procedure in the package, which may not be desirable.

Comment: Before I answer, can you explain why you want to know?  Not trying to be a pain, just trying to understand what exactly you want to do.  Why is it important for you to know whether the package has state?  Also, are you just interested in knowing if a package has state, and therefore could, at some point encounter ORA-4068?  Or, for a stateful package, are you interested in knowing whether the current state of the package is valid, invalid, or uninitialized?

Comment: Stateful packages can be annoying because if a change is made while there is a session open, it can lead to users getting errors. I have this problem with one package, which I was refactoring to make stateless and having some trouble (which will be the topic of a future SO question), so it would be nice to have an easy way to tell if the package is stateless or not. Also, which other packages in the database are stateful and could also potentially cause this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to be able to list all packages that may potentially have state.

What you're looking for is just packages that have any global variables or constants. For a single package, this is quite simple by inspection. To look across all packages in a schema, however, you could use PL/Scope:

First, log in as the schema owner, turn on PL/Scope in your session:

```
alter session set plscope_settings='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';
```

Then, recompile all your package bodies.

Then, run this query to find all the variables and constants declared at the package level:

```
select object_name AS package,
       type,
       name AS variable_name
from user_identifiers
where object_type IN ('PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY')
and usage = 'DECLARATION'
and type in ('VARIABLE','CONSTANT')
and usage_context_id in (
  select usage_id
  from user_identifiers
  where type = 'PACKAGE'
  );
```

I'd suggest the resulting list of packages will be your target.

If you're on 11gR2, constants no longer cause this problem, so you'd use this query instead:

```
select object_name AS package,
       type,
       name AS variable_name
from user_identifiers
where object_type IN ('PACKAGE','PACKAGE BODY')
and usage = 'DECLARATION'
and type = 'VARIABLE'
and usage_context_id in (
  select usage_id
  from user_identifiers
  where type = 'PACKAGE'
  );
```

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. In 11g, packages with all `CONSTANT` package variables are considered stateless, but your query will return them.

Comment: eaolson, that's not quite correct. In 11gR1, constants *do* cause the package to have state; this was fixed in 11gR2. I've edited the question to note this.

Comment: I think the select has an issue when more packages exist in the user schema, so the subselect should be extended to
   `AND usage_context_id IN (SELECT usage_id
                              FROM user_identifiers i2
                             WHERE TYPE = 'PACKAGE'
                               AND i2.object_name = i.object_name)`
Note join on **AND i2.object_name = i.object_name** at the end, and user_identifiers in parent select has to be aliased **i**.
But great answer nevertheless!

Comment: Thanks @GWu, you may be right. I made up these queries based on a small test schema. According to the docs `user_identifiers.usage_id` is unique within an object.