# Is there a way of discovering which public constants are defined in a package header?

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

I'm trying to write a tool to unit-test a lot of Oracle procedures in packages which represent our API. The API procedures rely on package header constants, and to my knowledge there is no view which describes which of these are available. I've looked through the Oracle docs but haven't found anything relevant.

Is there a way of discovering which public constants are defined in a package header? SQL or PL/SQL is fine.

I imagine the answer is no, and that I'm going to have to come up with a wrapper function, like as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178830/how-to-use-a-package-constant-in-sql-select-statement), but I just thought I'd ask in case I was missing something clever.

Thanks.

Comment: What Oracle Database version are you on?

Comment: If you're able to (re-)compile the API with PL/Scope enabled, [this answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11043498/266304). Otherwise I don't think that kind of information is stored in the data dictionary.

Comment: @AlexPoole that's actually perfect - make that an answer and I'll accept it? Thanks!

Comment: I can't really do a link as an answer, and Jeffery Kemp had done all the hard work anyway. I could flag this as a duplicate but that doesn't feel quite right either. @IanCarpenter added and then deleted a similar answer earlier; if he reinstates that it could be a good compromise?

Comment: @Alex. Thanks I deleted my answer as it wasn't of a high enough quality! (it didn't mention the critical recompilation step).

Comment: I think my edit takes care of that Ian - voting to undelete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the required information from the *_IDENTIFIERS static database views.

First, enable PL/Scope and recompile your packages, as per [Is there any way to determine if a package has state in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042712/is-there-any-way-to-determine-if-a-package-has-state-in-oracle/11043498#11043498)

The following query returns the public constants and variables.

```
SELECT ui.object_name, 
       ui.name,
       ui.type
  FROM user_identifiers ui
 WHERE ui.object_type = 'PACKAGE'
  AND  ui.usage       = 'DECLARATION'
  AND  ui.type IN ('CONSTANT', 'VARIABLE')
ORDER BY ui.object_name, 
         ui.name
/
```